# What is the complexity of multiple runs of an O(n log n) algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If the problem size is n, and every time an algorithm reduces the problem size by half, I believe the complexity is O (n log n) e..g merge sort. So, basically you are running a (log n) algorithm (the comparison) n times...

Now the problem is, if I have a problem of size n. My algorithm is able to reduce the size by half in a run and each run takes O(n log n). What is the complexity in this case?

Comment: It would be easier to calculate this with the algorithm posted in my opinion

Comment: Merge sort is O(n*logn) because it performs the recursive call twice after reducing the size by half. If it only made the recursive call once, it would be O(n) (see for example quickselect algorithm). So you need to be more specific about the algorithm you're talking about in order to analyze its complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem takes n steps at size n, plus an additional run at size floor(n/2) when n > 1, then it takes O(n) time in total: n + n/2 + n/4 + ... =~ 2n = O(n).

Similarly, if each run takes time O(n log n) and an additional run at size floor(n/2) when n > 1, the total time is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of the problem gets halved in each iteration and at each level the time taken is `n log n`, the recurrence relation is

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + n log n
```

Applying Master theorem,

Comparing with `T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)`, we have a=1 and b=2.

Hence n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> = n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>1</sup> 
          = n<sup>0</sup> = 1.

Thus f(n) = n log n > n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>.

Applying Master theorem we get T(n) = Θ(f(n)) = Θ(n log n).

Hence the complexity is T(n) =  **Θ(n log n)**.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT after comments:

If the size of the problem halves at every run, you'll have log(n) runs to complete it. Since every run take n*log(n) time, you'll have log(n) times n*log(n) runs. The total complexity will be:

```
O(n log(n)^2)
```

Comment: No. `n` gets divided by 2 at each "run".

Comment: But why is it n if n is reduced by half everytime?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that comes to O(n^2 log n).   You create a geometric series of n + n/2 + n/4 + ... = 2n (for large n).  But you ignore the coefficient and just get the n.

This is fine unless you mean the inner nlogn to be the same n value as the outer n.

Edit:
I think that what the OP means here is that each run the inner nlogn also gets havled.  In other words,

nlogn + n/2 log n/2 + n/4 log n/4 + ... + n/2^(n - 1) log n/2^(n-1)

If this is the case, then one thing to consider is that at some point

2^(n-1) > n

At that point the log breaks down (because log of a number between 0 and 1 is negative).  But, you don't really need the log as all there will be is 1 operation in these iterations.  So from there on you are just adding 1s.

This occurs at the log n / log 2.  So, for the first log n / log 2 iterations, we have the sum as we had above, and after that it is just a sum of 1s.

nlogn + n/2 log n/2 + n/4 log n/4 + ... + n/2^(log n / log 2) log n/2^(log n / log 2) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 ... (n - log n / log 2) times

Unfortunately, this expression is not an easy one to simplify...

Comment: Where did you get the n^2 from?

Comment: n ( n log n ) = n^2 log n.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by n then?

Comment: The geometric series I described gives you a 2n but for O-calculation you drop the 2 and just use n.  I just updated the post though because I think my original understanding of the question is not what the OP meant.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand the question, the first run completes in (proportional to) nlogn. The second run has only n/2 left, so completes in n/2log(n/2), and so on.

For large n, which is what you assume when analyzing the time-complexity, log(n/2) = (logn - log2) is to be replaced by logn.

summing over "all" steps:
log(n) * (n + n/2 + n/4 ...) = 2n log(n), i.e. time complexity nlogn

In other words: the time complexity is the same as for your first/basic step, all others together "only" contributing the same amount once more